# Is there a way to display a details view in .NET MAUI, like you do with the <details> tag in html?

Tags: view, maui

Hello I am trying to display data on labels and I want to provide extra details about the data, when the user clicks on a button e.g. .
I know there is the  tag in html, where you can define a summary and the details below.

Is there a way, or even better a ContentView, which can do that in .NET MAUI?

I've thought about adding a temporary label under the summary label, with the details, but that looks weird and is not intuitive.

Comment: please show a minimum of your code, or what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by details you mean a **collapse / expander** (which seem to be what [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) is in html) you can use the [expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/expander) from the .net maui community toolkit :

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <Label Text="Baboon"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="Medium" />
    </Expander.Header>
    <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="10">
        <Image Source="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Papio_anubis_%28Serengeti%2C_2009%29.jpg/200px-Papio_anubis_%28Serengeti%2C_2009%29.jpg"
               Aspect="AspectFill"
               HeightRequest="120"
               WidthRequest="120" />
        <Label Text="Baboons are African and Arabian Old World monkeys belonging to the genus Papio, part of the subfamily Cercopithecinae."
               FontAttributes="Italic" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</Expander>
```

Otherwise if you just want to provide some additional texte about an element I would go with [tooltips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/tooltips?view=net-maui-7.0).

```
<Button Text="Save"
    ToolTipProperties.Text="Click to Save your data" />
```

Comment: The expander class is just what I needed thank you!